# StreamRetryTemplate for Spring Cloud Streams not retrying in integration tests

Tags: kotlin, spring-cloud-stream, wiremock, spring-retry, retrytemplate

We are utilizing Spring Cloud Streams that listen to a Kafka topic and call a rest service. We also implement a custom StreamRetryTemplate to specify what kind of errors we deem recoverable and which we do not. I cannot get consistent results between how it works at runtime and how it works in integration tests.

I've verified in debug mode that the exception is being thrown properly and that the RetryTemplate is being injected in properly but it just doesn't seem to be utilized in my integration tests.

```
@EnableBinding(Sink::class)
class MyListener(private val myService: Service) {

  @StreamListener(Sink.Input)
  fun consume(@Payload msg: MyMessage) = myService.process(msg)

  @SteamRetryTemplate
  fun getRetryTemplate() = RetryTemplate()
}
```

When I run this app and myService throws an exception I expect it to be retried, and it does so perfectly. But when I write integration tests with a wiremock server and have myService throw an exception it does not retry. I have assert statements to verify how many times my wiremock endpoint is hit.

Am I missing something specifically for retries to work in integration tests?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you using the test binder or the embedded kafka broker? The test binder is rather limited; using the embedded broker is preferred for full integration testing.

See [Testing Applications in the Spring for Apache Kafka Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/#testing).

**EDIT**

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableBinding(Sink.class)
public class So55855151Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So55855151Application.class, args);
    }

    @StreamListener(Sink.INPUT)
    public void listen(String in) {
        System.out.println(in);
        throw new RuntimeException("fail");
    }

    @StreamRetryTemplate
    public RetryTemplate retrier() {
        return new RetryTemplate();
    }

}
```

```
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.group=input
spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers=${spring.embedded.kafka.brokers}
```

```java
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@EmbeddedKafka
public class So55855151ApplicationTests {

    @Autowired
    private KafkaTemplate<byte[], byte[]> template;

    @Autowired
    private RetryTemplate retrier;

    @Test
    public void test() throws InterruptedException {
        CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(5);
        this.retrier.registerListener(new RetryListener() {

            @Override
            public <T, E extends Throwable> boolean open(RetryContext context, RetryCallback<T, E> callback) {
                System.out.println("open");
                latch.countDown();
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public <T, E extends Throwable> void close(RetryContext context, RetryCallback<T, E> callback,
                    Throwable throwable) {

                System.out.println("close");
                latch.countDown();
            }

            @Override
            public <T, E extends Throwable> void onError(RetryContext context, RetryCallback<T, E> callback,
                    Throwable throwable) {

                System.out.println("onError: " + throwable);
                latch.countDown();
            }

        });

        this.template.send("input", "test".getBytes());
        assertThat(latch.await(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)).isTrue();
    }

}
```

Comment: I'm using the EmbeddedKafkaBroker with a WireMockServer. Thanks for the documentation link, I'll for sure give this a read through and see if it has any answers for me.

Comment: If you uses Spring Initializr to create your project, you need to remove the `spring-cloud-stream-test-support` jar from the pom (or exclude the test binder in your test). Otherwise the test binder will win. I just tested a custom `StreamRetryTemplate` and can see it being used in the test case.

Comment: I added my test.

Comment: thank you so much for this. Sorry I've been delayed in responding. Your example has gotten me very close! Do you happen to have a good example to get this exact or similar test setup to work with an Avro serialized object instead of the simple byte[]? I've tried using the example here <https://objectpartners.com/2018/08/21/testing-with-spring-kafka-and-mockschemaregistryclient/>  for the MockSchemaRegistryClient, but I am unable to get it to work.

Comment: Sorry, I've not worked with the schema registry. I suggest you ask a new question with more details.

Comment: I'm marking your answer as correct since I'm confident that had I not been using Avro (my original question clearly didn't state that) you would have been spot on. Thanks for your help!